# run piped bash commnads from python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I want to run the following bash command from within my python script

```
tail input.txt | grep <pattern>
```

I have written the following lines

```
bashCommand = "tail input.txt | grep <pattern>'"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But this ends up simply printing out the tail of the input file and not the pattern I am trying to grep. How do I circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`. This will run the command through the shell. If you do this you will need to pass a string instead of an list:

> process = subprocess.Popen("tail input.txt | grep ", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
> print process.communicate()`

You can find a more detailed explanation here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282839/why-wont-this-bash-command-run-when-called-by-python

Comment: Thanks Robbe! Is there a way to make it work with a variable? Where <pattern> can be substituted with a var?

Comment: Yes, you can always use string formatting. Or you can use the solution that chepner came up with. His solutions is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing the pipe in Python, rather than the shell.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(["tail", "input.txt"], stdout=PIPE)
process = Popen(["grep", "<pattern>"], stdin=p1.stdout)
```